# Salesforce Communities

Tags: community

I am currently learning Salesforce communities. I'm doing my due diligence by reading Salesforce docs and Salesforce Case Implementations like [here](http://www.eustaceconsulting.com/blog/general/custom-salesforce-knowledge-with-visualforce-case-study-with-shoretelsky/). I came accross couple of Salesforce community sites like [Logitech](http://support.logitech.com/) and [Home Depot](http://community.homedepot.com/). Can any body help me to know which community feature is used to build [this particular](http://community.homedepot.com/howto/DiscussionDetail/Allure-flooring-against-bathtub-9065000000008do) Home Depot page? Is it out of the box feature or is a custom one?

Answer (score 1):

Page is using Chatter Answer feature of Salesforce.Also you can customize the deafualt  feature of this module by installing certain application from appExchange and incorporating it by VisualForce page.

Thanks...